# Keyboard android event?

Tags: android, events, keyboard

In one of my classes I have two `EditText` and a `Button` on the bottom of the screen. When I select one of the `EditText`s the keyboard appears. The problem is that then the `EditText` and the `Button` are moved to the front of the screen in order to see what you are writing. But, above the `EditText` I have two `TextView` and when I write something to the `EditText`, the `TextView`s disappears from the screen.

Can I do something like this: when the user writes something in the `Edittext`, only the `EditText` moves up, and the rest aren't affected?

Comment: you can use setOnFocusChangeListener and layout parameter for this...

Comment: you want to bring the editText to center of screen during its editing??

Comment: yes, but to not affect the textviews fron the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

THis code animates your edtxt from top to bottom:

DO CHANGES ACCORDINGLY:

```
edtxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
if(hasFocus)
{   
TranslateAnimation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -100,0 );   
    slide.setDuration(1000);   
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    edtxt.startAnimation(slide);  
}

}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute to your `Activity` in the `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

This will cause the screen to adjust correctly when the software keyboard opens.

Answer (score 0):

You can overrite onConfigurationChanged method and check the keyboard up/down status

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);


    if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO)
    {

    } 
    else if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES) 
    {

    }
}

<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```